# How to restrict length of cell in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have such a list view [image]

And there is a `.xalm`

```
...
<ListView
                x:Name="LVLog"
                ToolTip="Log of task(s) execution"
                Background="WhiteSmoke"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
...
```

And there is how I add items in `LVLog`

```
LVLog.Items.Add(message.Log);
```

As you can see if line a long enough it goes out of the borders and user need to scroll horizontaly in order to read log up to the end.

Question is: is there is a way to write line at the next line if it came to the borders?

Comment: You can define item template for list view

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski do you have a example?

Comment: Have a look at this simple [sample](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Ok, as far as I understand I can add template that will define `TextBox`, but anyway if I add long text to `TextBox` it will goes out of borders, no?

Comment: You can restrict textblock size, or use wrappanel as items panel template and restrict item width

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski do you mean restrict it hardcoded? like Width = 150 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `TextBlock` as an `ItemTemplate` and set `TextTrimming` on it. So the text will be trimmed

> Long long lo..

and the full text you will see in tooltip:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding ...}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If you want to have more lines, then just set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` in the `TextBlock`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: But as I mentioned in question I don't need to trim a text, I need to write it on the next line...